# Rxjava Android saving to database after network call?

Tags: rx-java, mvp, rx-android

I am learning rxjava on android and would like to accomplish the task of fetching data from the internet, showing to view and saving it to database.

Once data is fetched from internet, I would like to in Parallel,

- Display fetched data to the View
- Save to Database (on computation thread)

Also,

- If network fetch is success, then display to view + save to database (parallel)
- If network fetch is failure, the skip the whole process (onError())
- If saving to database fails, ignore and continue displaying to View.

My problem is that if database part fails, nothing is displayed on the view.

```
 @Override
  public Observable<List<NearByPlacesDetail>> getNearbyTouristSpotsList(String latlng) {
    Observable<NearByPlacesMain> nearByPlacesMainObservable = googleMapApi.getTouristAttractions(latlng);

return nearByPlacesMainObservable
  .map(NearByPlacesMain::getResults)
  .onExceptionResumeNext(new Observable<List<NearByPlacesDetail>>() {
    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super List<NearByPlacesDetail>> observer) {
      Throwable throwable = new Throwable("Network fetch error");
      Timber.e(throwable, "Error fetching data from internet.");
      observer.onError(throwable);
    }
  })
  .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
  .doOnNext(nearByPlacesDetails -> {
    databaseManager.getDatabase().delete(); // Force failure
    databaseManager.savePlacesList(nearByPlacesDetails);
  })
  .onExceptionResumeNext(new Observable<List<NearByPlacesDetail>>() {
    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super List<NearByPlacesDetail>> observer) {
      Timber.e("Error saving to database.");
      observer.onComplete();
    }
  });
```

Presenter

```
getPlacesList.execute(new PlacesListObserver(), GetPlacesListUseCase.Params.forLocation(lat, lng));
```

Base UseCase (Domain Module)

```
  public void execute(DisposableObserver<T> observer, Params params) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(observer);

    final Observable<T> observable = this.buildUseCaseObservable(params)
      .subscribeOn(subscribeScheduler)
      .observeOn(observeScheduler);

    addDisposable(observable.subscribeWith(observer));
  }
```

Comment: `Network -> Database -> View` makes more sense to me

Answer (score 1):

To my point of view , a use case is for one action .

My suggestion here is to create two use case , one for fetching data and the other one for saving data into database, it's better for readability and maintainability.

So once the data is fetched , data should be return to the presenter, for exemple :

```
@Override
public void onDataFetched(Data data){
    mPresenterView.displayData(data);
    mDatabaseUseCase.execute(databaseObserver, databaseParams);
}
```

So even if the database failed the data is displayed.

Hope this helps.
Sorry for my english.